# How do I enable word wrap in all open splits?

Tags: vim

I am using vimdiff to compare three files side by side. How do I enable word wrap inside all three splits without having to switch to each and issue :set wrap three times? I would rather not have word wrap enabled by default though.

Comment: To clarify, you are looking to have a command apply to multiple buffers without setting it as the default?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I think I found the answer: `:windo`.

Comment: @mike: That's the answer I was going to post, but I suggest you post it so you can get the karma.

Answer (score 11):

```
:windo set wrap
```

Just answer it , got the hint from the comments.

Comment: For the sake of the argument, here is how to disable it too: `:windo set nowrap` also to set it only one of the window panes (Ctrl+W to switch panes) `:set wrap`

Comment: Also, you can toggle the setting with `:windo set wrap!` and `:set wrap!` . (Convenient to map a keystroke to that to toggle the setting).